# overriding global css that came from node_modules next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, node-modules, styling

I am trying to override css style for a rc-pagination component that came with a css file that i've already imported it on the root component **_App** and when i navigate to the index.css styling sheet of this component and try to override no thing changes, could anyone explain this?

[The css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWkKP.png)

[The browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONej8.png)

Comment: You have to make sure your own css is more specific or has the same specificity but is executed after the original css. If this does not answer your question you will need to add more details. Minimal we need the original css en your css but preferably a snippet that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Iam already trying to edit the root style that Imported from the noude_modules  but the browser shows the default styling of it, like the attached screenshots shows

Comment: It's not possible to debug screenshots. We need the code to reproduce your issue, preferably as a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have to close the serve and reserve again.